# Why can all dataframe columns be accessed in the series passed to the aggregating function when using DataFrameGroupBy.agg?

Tags: python, pandas

I made an observation while playing around with the `apply` and `agg` methods of `DataFrameGroupBy` objects which I cannot explain.

---

**Introduction**

I understand the following code, but it may be useful as an introduction for the question.

I am grouping the `DataFrame` `my_df`

```
   key col0 col1
0    1    A    B
1    1    C    D
2    2    E    F
3    2    G    H
```

by the `'key'` column and then `apply` the function

```
def func(df): 
     return ''.join(df['col0'] + df['col1'])
```

which produces

```
>>> my_df.groupby('key').apply(func)
key
1    ABCD
2    EFGH
dtype: object
```

This works as expected. I have access to the columns `'col0'` and `'col1'` because the "grouped chunks" passed to `func` when using `apply` are dataframes.

---

**Question**

I don't understand why no `KeyError` is raised when using `agg` instead of `apply` with the same function.

```
>>> my_df.groupby('key').agg(func)                                     
     col0  col1
key            
1    ABCD  ABCD
2    EFGH  EFGH
```

As far as I understand, when using `agg` then `func` gets passed a `Series` *for each group for each column* of `my_df`, so the `df` argument should be of type `Series`, and trying to do `df['col0']` and `df['col1']` should produce a `KeyError`.

Why does `agg` produce a result? Where is my `KeyError`?

---

**Research**

I confirmed that `df` is a `Series` which cannot be indexed into with `df['col0']` and `df['col1']` with the debugger.

Yet `my_df.groupby('key').agg(func)` magically works.

Setup:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb
import sys

def set_trace():
    Pdb().set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)

def func(df): 
    set_trace() 
    return ''.join(df['col0'] + df['col1'])
```

Usage:

```
>>> my_df.groupby('key').agg(func)
> <ipython-input-258-9f34bde72bce>(9)func()
      6 
      7 def func(df):
      8      set_trace()
----> 9      return ''.join(df['col0'] + df['col1'])
     10 

ipdb> type(df)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
ipdb> df
0    A
1    C
Name: col0, dtype: object
ipdb> df['col0']
*** KeyError: 'col0'
ipdb> df['col1']
*** KeyError: 'col1'
```

Comment: seems agg apply the function number of column times

Comment: That would explain how the result has two columns, but not why `df['col0']` and `df['col1']` don't raise when `df = pd.Series(['A', 'C'], index=[0, 1])`,  right?

Comment: @WesMcKinney this might one for you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually does raise a `KeyError` which you can see when wrapping the access in `try/except`:

```
In [23]: def func(df): 
    ...:     print(type(df))
    ...:     print(df)
    ...:     print()
    ...:     try:
    ...:         df['col0']
    ...:     except KeyError:
    ...:         print('[Error]')
    ...:     return ''.join(df['col0'] + df['col1'])
    ...: 
    ...:
In [24]: df.groupby('key').agg(func)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    A
1    C
Name: col0, dtype: object
[Error]

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    A
1    C
Name: col0, dtype: object
[Error]

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    A
1    C
Name: 1, dtype: object
[Error]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   key col0 col1
0    1    A    B
1    1    C    D

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   key col0 col1
2    2    E    F
3    2    G    H
```

That `KeyError` seems to be excepted by the invoking function and hence it is silenced.

Checking some source code shows that `agg` calls actually [this function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f160c7d7c63c11f8807ddd1e653a95821e82269d/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L183). From here it first goes to [this function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f160c7d7c63c11f8807ddd1e653a95821e82269d/pandas/core/base.py#L560) which returns `None` if `arg` is a function (which is our case). And finally it goes [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f160c7d7c63c11f8807ddd1e653a95821e82269d/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L200) where the `try / except Exception` is performed.

Comment: Check out: `def func(df): print(type(df)); return 1`. It prints `Series` four times when used with `agg` on OP's frame (which makes sense to me) and nothing else. Falling back to `apply` with a `DataFrame` seems to be done on `KeyError`. Which is ... confusing. If the user wants `apply`, make them use `apply`?

Comment: Also, why does the documentation say: "If a function, must either work when passed a DataFrame or when passed to `DataFrame.apply`"? Shouldn't it be "If a function, must either work when passed a **Series** or when passed to `DataFrame.apply`"?

Comment: @timgeb It seems that there are lots of undocumented implications about how things should be handled "off-road" (e.g. when inputs are not as expected) hidden inside the pandas package. And often these cases are handled in such an obscure way that it's hard to guess from reading the source code. But can we agree that for this particular case it does fallback on `apply`?

Answer (score 2):

As @W-B says, `agg` passes the entire DataFrame to `func`. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-agg),

> **func** :    *function, string, dictionary, or list of string/functions*        Function to use for aggregating the data. **If a function, must either
>   work when passed a DataFrame or when passed to `DataFrame.apply.`**

I believe this means that the function is actually dispatched by `apply`, which is known to operate on the entire DataFrame.

You can expose this with a simple `print` call inside `func`:

```
def func(df):
    print(type(df))
    return ''.join(df['col0'] + df['col1'])
```

```
df.groupby('key').agg(func)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Out[87]: 
     col0  col1
key            
1    ABCD  ABCD
2    EFGH  EFGH
```

So it does get two calls with a DataFrame. But it also gets 3 calls with Series arguments and I cannot explain why this is, perhaps a bug maybe (I cannot see it documented anywhere).

---

Okay, after thinking about this, this is the best I could come up with. Now, `agg` isn't sure how your function wants to handle the data, so it will try two ways and use the output of whatever works first as a Series. This seems like an implementation detail, but Series is the first method used to pass the data in. If that does not work, the fallback is to pass a DataFrame and hope it succeeds. Let me see if I can get this to work in an example...

```
from itertools import count
c = count(0)

def func(x):
    i = next(c)
    print(i, type(x))
    if i <3:
        return 'xyz'
    return ((df['col0'] + df['col1']).tolist())

df.groupby('key').agg(func)

0 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
3 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Out[126]: 
    col0              col1
key                       
1    xyz               xyz
2    xyz  [AB, CD, EF, GH]
```

Next, changing the loop condition, we have:

```
def func(x):
    i = next(c)
    print(i, type(x))
    if i in {0, 1}:
        return 'xyz'
    return ((x['col0'] + x['col1']).tolist())

df.groupby('key').agg(func)

0 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
3 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
4 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
5 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
6 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Out[157]: 
    col0 col1
key          
1     AB   CD
2     EF   GH
```

And, changing `i in {0, 1}` to `i in {0, 4}`,

```
0 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
3 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
4 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
5 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Out[158]: 
    col0 col1
key          
1    xyz  xyz
2     EF   GH
```

Notice how the number of type of function varies based on what is returned each time.

Comment: But you used `apply`. Doesn't my debugger session prove that `df` is a `Series` when using `agg`?

Comment: @actual_panda Yes, but your debugger apparently did not step far enough to see that it eventually gets the DataFrame. Now, _why_ it also gets a Series is an interesting question. I think that might be a bug, but I can't be sure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still confused why `df['col0']` does not end everything with a `KeyError` for the series that are passed.

Comment: Are you intentionally or unintentionally using `df` as a global variable in `func`?

Comment: @timgeb That was unintentional but I ended up with some interesting output, so I decided to keep it there as an example of how the data is passed to `agg` and what is computed.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but it might be more interesting with `x['col0']`... if `i >= 3`.

Comment: @timgeb They do shed a bit of light but I find the output still a bit confusing.

Comment: I shouldn't have come here. I thought I understood `agg` and `apply`.

Comment: @actual_panda any luck figuring this out?